# Язык "C" конвертация bmp в jpeg

Tags: c, windows, изображения

Прошел основы языка. Нужен конвертер bmp в JPEG средствами Windows без таскания лишних библиотек. Как это сделать? Много гуглил везде на c++ примеры.

Comment: Не думаю, что в таких вопросах очень широко используется специфика С++. Но вот без лишних библиотек (т.е. самостоятельно), да еще при *прошел основы языка* - сомневаюсь, что так получится...

Comment: Harry, в какую сторону копать, что читать, чтоб получилось? Именно на тему графики

Comment: Копать в сторону готовых библиотек.

Comment: Используйте [WIC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wic/-wic-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например с помощью [GDI+ Flat API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-flatapi-flat):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

typedef struct _GdiplusStartupInput
{
    UINT32 GdiplusVersion;             // Must be 1  (or 2 for the Ex version)
    void* DebugEventCallback; // Ignored on free builds
    BOOL SuppressBackgroundThread;     // FALSE unless you're prepared to call 
                                       // the hook/unhook functions properly
    BOOL SuppressExternalCodecs;       // FALSE unless you want GDI+ only to use
                                       // its internal image codecs.
} GdiplusStartupInput;

typedef struct _GdiplusStartupOutput
{      
    void* NotificationHook;
    void* NotificationUnhook;
} GdiplusStartupOutput;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{       

  HANDLE g ;
  int  (__stdcall *GdiplusStartup)(ULONG_PTR *,const GdiplusStartupInput *,GdiplusStartupOutput *);
  int  (__stdcall *GdiplusShutdown)(ULONG_PTR *);  
  int  (__stdcall *GdipLoadImageFromFile)(WCHAR* filename, void **image);
  int  (__stdcall *GdipSaveImageToFile) (void *image,  WCHAR* filename, void* clsidEncoder,  void* encoderParams);
  GdiplusStartupInput input = {1,0};
  GdiplusStartupOutput output = {0};
  ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
  CLSID   encoderClsid ={0x557cf401,0x1a04,0x11d3,0x9a,0x73,0x00,0x00,0xf8,0x1e,0xf3,0x2e}; //image/jpeg
  void* pImage=NULL;
  int result;   

  //загрузка указателей на функции
  g= LoadLibraryA("gdiplus.dll");
  GdiplusStartup= (int  (__stdcall *)(ULONG_PTR *,const GdiplusStartupInput *,GdiplusStartupOutput *))GetProcAddress((HMODULE)g,"GdiplusStartup");
  GdiplusShutdown= (int  (__stdcall *)(ULONG_PTR *))GetProcAddress((HMODULE)g,"GdiplusShutdown");
  GdipLoadImageFromFile  = (int  (__stdcall *)(WCHAR* filename, void **image))GetProcAddress((HMODULE)g,"GdipLoadImageFromFile");
  GdipSaveImageToFile  = (int  (__stdcall *) (void *image,  WCHAR* filename, void* clsidEncoder,  void* encoderParams))GetProcAddress((HMODULE)g,"GdipSaveImageToFile");

  //инициализация GDI+
  result = GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken,&input,&output);
  if(result != 0) {wprintf(L"GdiplusStartup failed: error %d\n",result);getchar();return 1;}

  //загрузка Image
  result = GdipLoadImageFromFile(L"d:\\image.bmp",&pImage);
  if(result != 0) {wprintf(L"GdipLoadImageFromFile failed: error %d\n",result);getchar();return 1;}

  //сохранение Image
  result = GdipSaveImageToFile(pImage,L"d:\\image.jpg",&encoderClsid,NULL);  
  if(result != 0) {wprintf(L"GdipSaveImageToFile failed: error %d\n",result);getchar();return 1;}

  wprintf(L"Image saved successfully\n");
  GdiplusShutdown(&gdiplusToken);  

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```